# For given $n\times n$ matrix $A$ singular matrix, prove that $\operatorname{rank}(\operatorname{adj}A) \leq 1$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

For given $n\times n$ matrix $A$ singular matrix, prove that $\operatorname{rank}(\operatorname{adj}A) \leq 1$

So from the properties of the adjugate matrix we know that
$$ A \cdot \operatorname{adj}(A) = \operatorname{det}(A)\cdot I$$

Since $A$ is singular we know that $\operatorname{det}(A) = 0$, thus
$$ A \cdot \operatorname{adj}(A) = 0$$

This is where I'm getting lost, I think I should say that for the above to happen one of the two, $A$ or $\operatorname{adj}(A)$ would have to be the $0$ matrix, but if $A = 0$ then $\operatorname{adj}(A) = 0$ for sure, which means I said nothing.

A leading hint is needed.

Comment: Hmm, when $A$ is singular, isn't one of its eigenvalues zero, therefore $\det(A)=0$...

Comment: we haven't learned *eigenvalues* yet so I believe we're not supposed to use it...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Since $A$ is singular, $\mbox{rank}A\leq n-1$.

**Case 1:** $\mbox{rank}A\leq n-2$. Then $A$ contains no invertible submatrix of order $n-1$. So every minor of order $n-1$ is zero. What can you conclude about $\mbox{adj}(A)$?

**Case 2:** $\mbox{rank}A= n-1$. By rank-nullity, we get $\dim\ker A=1$. Now $A\cdot \mbox{adj}(A)=0$ means that the range of $\mbox{adj}(A)$ is contained in $\ker A$. So...

Comment: Why can you tell that because $A$ is singular $\rightarrow \space\space rankA \leq n-1$?

Comment: @Georgey rank $A=n$ iff $A$ is surjective iff $A$ is invertible.

Comment: I don't even know what a surjective matrix *embarrassed*

Comment: @Georgey Don't you know, at least, that a square $n\times n$ matrix is invertible iff it has full rank $n$? So if it is not invertible (i.e. singular) it has rank $\leq n-1$.

Comment: I didn't know that - now I do.

Comment: @Georgey Great. It is helpful to understand the rank of an $n\times m$ matrix as the dimension of the range of the linear map induced by $A:K^m\rightarrow K^n$ on the column vectors. Then you see that the rank of $A$ is $n$ iff the range of $A$ is the whole of $K^n$, that is $A$ is surjective. In the square $m=n$ case, this is equivalent to $A$ being invertible by the rank-nullity theorem.

Answer (score 6):

This is an old question, but I would like to add a solution that only uses properties of matrices i.e. no abstract algebra.
Sylvester's rank inequality states that for two matrices $X,Y \in \mathcal{M_n(\mathbb{C})}$ we have that $\operatorname{rank}(XY)\ge \operatorname{rank}X+\operatorname{rank} Y-n$.
Since $A$ is singular, we have $\operatorname{rank}A\le n-1$.
We have the equality $A\cdot \operatorname{adj}A=O_n$.
Hence, from Sylvester's rank inequality $0=\operatorname{rank}(A\cdot \operatorname{adj}A)\ge \operatorname{rank}A + \operatorname{rank}(\operatorname{adj}A)-n$.(1)
Case 1. $\operatorname{rank}A\le n-2=>\operatorname{adj}(A)=O_n$ as in Julien's solution.
Case 2. $\operatorname{rank}A=n-1$.
From (1) we have that $\operatorname{rank}(\operatorname{adj}A)\le 1$, so $\operatorname{rank}(\operatorname{adj}A)\in \{0,1\}$.
If $\operatorname{rank}(\operatorname{adj}A)=0$, then $\operatorname{adj}A=O_n$ and this contradicts $\operatorname{rank} A=n-1$.
Hence, $\operatorname{rank}(\operatorname{adj}A)=1$ in this case.
In both cases $\operatorname{rank}(\operatorname{adj}A)\le 1$.

Comment: Most simple yet elegant solution to the question

Answer (score 0):

Since the adjugate is [anti-multiplicative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix#Properties), and every matrix $A$ is a product $A = T D S$, where $T$, $S$ are of determinant $1$, and $D$ is a diagonal matrix, it's enough to check for $A$ diagonal. Now it's easy.

Another approach, pure algebra. It is enough to check that every minor of order $2$ of the matrix $\operatorname{adj}(A)$ is $0$ if $\det A = 0$. Now we have the complement formula for the minors of the adjoint matrix

$$M_{ij, kl}( \operatorname{adj}(A)) = \pm \cdot M_{\overline{ij}, \overline{kl}}(A) \cdot \det A$$
(works for any commutative ring)
( Jacobi formula for minors- see Aitken-- Determinants and Matrices)