# let $\dim(ker (A - \lambda I)) = 1$. why is $adj(A - \lambda I) \ne 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus, adjoint-operators

Let $\lambda$ is eigenvalue of $A$ and  $\dim(\ker (A - \lambda I)) = 1$.($\lambda$ has geometric multiplcity one)
why is $\text{adj}(A - \lambda I) \ne 0$?

Comment: what leads you to believe that this is generally true?

Answer (score 0):

Let $M=A-\lambda I$; your are asking why $M$ having rank$~n-1$ implies that that adjugate matrix of $M$ is nonzero. This is because the rank is the size of the largest nonzero minor, and the adjugate of $M$ contains (up to sign) *all* size $n-1$ minors of $M$. The hypothesis says that at least one of those minors is nonzero, and so the adjugate of $M$ is nonzero.

For more information see answers to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/410402/18880) or [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/892039/18880).