# Rank of adjoint of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank, adjoint-operators

I need to prove these 3 statements, and I don't know how to start...

A is an nxn matrix:

1) if rank(A) = n then rank(adj(A)) = n

2) if rank(A) = n-1 then rank(adj(A)) = 1

2) if rank(A) < n-1 then rank(adj(A)) = 0

Comment: For the first one, try showing that if $A$ is invertible then $adj(A)$ is invertible also (I recommend using determinants). Then it will be obvious that if $A$ has full rank then $adj(A)$ will as well.

Comment: For the last one, not that a matrix has rank $r$ if and only if one of its $r\times r$ submatrices has a non-zero determinant.

Comment: I solved the question with these two links:
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/892039/is-adjoint-of-singular-matrix-singular-what-would-be-its-rank
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/410402/for-given-n-times-n-matrix-a-singular-matrix-prove-that-operatornamerank/410415#410415

the important relation that are used in these two solutions is given in Dr. Akbari's pamphlet. So, by using that relation the proof is straightforward:))) Now, you help me to solve question number 30 :)))