# What real matrices are adjugates?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

For $A$ a square matrix with elements in $\mathbb{R}$ ( or even $R$, a commutative ring), the adjugate $\operatorname{adj}(A)$ is the transpose of the cofactor matrix of $A$.

The question is: for what real $n\times n$ matrices $B$ does there exist a matrix $A$ with $\operatorname{adj} A=B$. In other works: what is the image of the map
$$\operatorname{adj} \colon M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R}) \to M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R})$$

What I've done:

We have the following formulas:

1. $\operatorname{adj}(A) \cdot A = A\cdot \operatorname{adj}(A) = \det A \cdot I$
2. $\det \operatorname{adj}(A)= (\det A)^{n-1}$
3. $ \operatorname{adj}(\alpha A) = \alpha^{n-1}\cdot \operatorname{adj}(A)$
4. $\operatorname{adj}( \operatorname{adj} (A)) = (\det A)^{n-2} A$
5. $\operatorname{adj}(A)\cdot \operatorname{adj}(B) = \operatorname{adj}(B A)$

From 2. we conclude: if $\det A \ne 0$, and $k$ such that $k^{n-1} = \det A^{n-2}$, then

$$\operatorname{adj} (\frac{1}{k} \operatorname{adj}(A))= \frac{(\det A)^{n-2}}{k^{n-1}} A = A$$

Now, if $n$ is even, we can always find such $k$. If $n$ is odd, then we'll need $\det A>0$ ( see also point 0.)

Conclusion: the  non-degenerate matrices  that are adjugates are : all of them if $n$ even, and those of determinant $>0$, for $n$ odd.

Now, consider the case $\det B= 0$. We want to find a matrix with adjugate $B$. Now, if $\operatorname{adj}(A)= B$, and $\det B=0$, then $(\det A)^{n-1} = 0$, and so $\det A=0$. Now, we'll have $\operatorname{adj}(\operatorname{adj}(A)) = \det(A)^{n-2} A=0$. (toss aside the simple case $n=2$). We conclude $B$ is of rank at most $n-2$.

Since $\operatorname{adj}$ is anti-multiplicative, and every matrix can be reduced to a diagonal form by left and right elementary operations, we can reduce to the case $B$ diagonal. Now, if $B = \operatorname{diag}(d_1, \ldots, d_n)$ ( with some of the $d_i$ $0$), $d_1$, $\ldots$, $d_r\ne 0$ and the rest $0$, and $B = \operatorname{adj}(A)$, then $B \cdot A = A \cdot B = \det(A) \cdot I_n = 0$, so $A$ has the first $r$ rows and columns $0$. If $r\ge 2$ we'll get $\operatorname{adj}(A)=0= B$, a contradiction. If $r=1$, we'll get in (many ways) $B = \operatorname{adj}(A)$, with a matrix $A$ with first row and column $0$.

Conclusion: If $n>2$,  the degenerate matrices that are adjugates are exactly those of rank $\le 1$ ( this is true for any field).

Any feedback would be appreciated!  Thank you for your attention!

Note: this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/410402/for-given-n-times-n-matrix-a-singular-matrix-prove-that-operatornamerank) on the site is related.